# tcpdump capture files analysis

Tags: analysis, latency, tcpdump

I generated some communications between client/server and captured the packets using tcpdump. Now I want to analyze those packets to measure latencies and some other information, like any packet lost or acks lost. Is there any way to do this. I was trying to write scripts in perl to analyze it. There is a perl implementation call net::tcpdump. But the documentation is not very detailed. I don't event know how to extract the time stamps.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I know wireshark has some analysis and stat tools. However, it's not very fit what i want to do. is there anyone can tell me how to script programming to analyze the dump files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch to Python, I have found [impacket](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Impacket) useful for writing some custom .pcap analysis scripts. The [tcptrace](http://www.tcptrace.org/) tool also has some analysis features not available in Wireshark

Answer (score -1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) has some packet statistical tools - and can read the capture files produced by tcpdump.